# Can't find anything to help with "Bone Weight Heating Failed"

Tags: bones

I've made this model in about an hour and a half, and I can't exactly pinpoint why the automatic weights aren't working when rigging it with Rigify.

It's been cleaned up (no double verts, decimated, remeshed),
It's not too dense, I've dealt with denser models with few issues.
All scales are set, and the rig is generated correctly. I've tried it without the mask (which is what I thought was the issue at first), and it's failing even then.
I'm stuck on what to do to get this model to work properly. .blend file below.

**Thank you for any assistance!**[image: Error in question.]
[Blender file.](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/db9vmwvy23b237rfvpa2e/CLEANEDTEST.blend?rlkey=a9q6bfw8ifjnm9pv4ttlz9wg4&dl=0)

Comment: the topology is super dense, you don't need such a dense mesh, plus it's going to be too heavy to animate, maybe first try to simplify it with some Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that's something I could definitely use later down the line. It seems the density wasn't the core problem, as it's still having trouble when at a reasonable size. I'll likely just chalk this as a broken model and move on.

Comment: So maybe share the simplified version so that we can check?

Comment: Of course. Here you are: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8yibnbej91hg29iiyvp5f/UNSUBDIVIDEDBODYTEST.blend?rlkey=165h95jkzex255unqfui5bpop&dl=0)

Comment: The topology is still super dense, plus it looks bad, do you really plan to use this object? You should retopologize it to make it look better and most of all make it lighter

Comment: I don't intend on using this for animation. It'll be used in the background of some rendered images, hence the lack of a face. I do wish to pose it, don't exactly want a t-posing figure ominously standing around. Thank you for your recommendations, however!